# Laravel send params from React to controller

Tags: reactjs, laravel, google-api, geolocation

I need to get the device's current location and then calculate the distance between that location and the company's registered address in the database and for that I'm using Laravel+React. In React I get the latitude and longitude with **navigator.geolocation** and then use a lib called **react-geocode** to get the current full address, such as name, city, state and zip code and then render this information in a global view in laravel. This works correctly.

With this information being rendered, I need to get this zip code and pass it to the controller that searches the company's data in the database and then use the google api to calculate the distance between the current address and the registered company's address. I don't know how to get this information (zipcode) which is being displayed in the view via reactjs.

Here is the location.js in React

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function (position) {
            // console.log("Latitude is :", position.coords.latitude);
            // console.log("Longitude is :", position.coords.longitude);

            Geocode.fromLatLng(
                position.coords.latitude,
                position.coords.longitude
            ).then(
                (response) => {
                    const address = response.results[0].formatted_address,
                        city =
                            response.results[0].address_components[3]
                                .long_name,
                        neighborhoodName =
                            response.results[0].address_components[2]
                                .long_name,
                        state =
                            response.results[0].address_components[4]
                                .short_name,
                        fromZipcode =
                            response.results[0].address_components[6]
                                .long_name;

                    setCityName(`${city}/${state}`);
                    setNeighborhood(neighborhoodName);
                    setZipcode(fromZipcode);
                },
                (error) => {
                    console.error("Error", error);
                }
            );
        });
    }
}, []);

return (
    <>
        {/* THIS SHOW THE ZIPCODE AND CITY NAME ON A SPAN TAG */}
        <span id="fromZipcode" value={zipcode}>
            Você esté em {`${neighborhood} - ${cityName}`}
        </span>
    </>
);
```

The laravel controller method **show** render a page with the user data and in this page I want to get the zipcode (that is render by react). I already tried to use request->input('zipcode') and request()->get('teste', null), but without success:

```
public function show($slug, Request $request)
{
    dd(request()->get('teste', null)); // I DON'T KNOW HOW TO GET THE ZIPCODE PARAMS FROM THE REACT/BLADE
    // dd($request->all());
    $client = $this->clientRepository->getClientBySlug($slug);
    $gallery = $client ? $this->clientRepository->getGalleryFromClient($client->id) : null;

    return view('site.client.index')->with(compact('client', 'gallery'));
}
```

Comment: I don't see/understand what your issue is... that is very important to outline when asking for help... also, what is currently happening and what would you like to happen... I took the time to extract that from you... What are you supposed to do with the `show` form? is it happening on React or first you use this method and then react shows? I have no idea what is the order, nor I see react sending anything to show...

Comment: I edited the question to try to explan a little better

Comment: It is still not clear... You are using show to show data, but you want to get the zipcode on React? Show us how is laravel and react connecting togheter, that is the part you need to add code for in the view (blade)

Comment: You are still not sharing how you are sending this data to Laravel... where is your AJAX? And it should be `$request->input('NAME')` in the controller, but please, share how you are sending the data to the controller...

Comment: but that's exactly what I want and can't do, share the data obtained by calling the api in react with laravel. The zip code is there, I already managed to get it with react, now I need a way to "get" this data in the controller.

Comment: I display the data in a span in the view (this is just a test to show that the data I want is correct coming from ReactJS): return (
        <>
            {/* THIS SHOW THE ZIPCODE AND CITY NAME ON A SPAN TAG */}
            <span id="fromZipcode" value={zipcode}>
                You are in {`${neighborhood} - ${cityName}`}
            </span>
        </>
    );
Now how to get this data in the controller?

Comment: Oh, so you have no idea how to do an AJAX call then? That is not clear on the question, but there are plenty of tutorials out there showing how to do a normal `fetch` call: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch